# Prove that for any positive integer $n$, the fractional part of $\sqrt{4n^2+n}$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{4}$.

Tags: number-theory, inequality

> Prove that for any positive integer $n$, the fractional part of $\sqrt{4n^2+n}$ is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Should I break this into cases? If $4n^2+n$ is a perfect square then obviously the fractional part is less than $\dfrac{1}{4}$. But if it is not a perfect square I must show it still is less.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $4n^2 < 4n^2+n < 4n^2+n+\frac{1}{16}$.

Answer (score 3):

you have $$4n^2< 4n^2+n < \left(2n+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$

Comment: Equivalently $2n<\sqrt {4n^2+n}=2n\sqrt {1+(4n^2)^{-1}}<2n(1+(1/2)(4n^2)^{-1}).$

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$(2n)^2<4n^2+n<(2n+1)^2$$
then $\lfloor\sqrt{4n^2+n}\rfloor=2n$. Now suppose that
$$(2n+x)^2=4n^2+n$$
for some $0<x<1$.
Then
$$4nx+x^2=n$$
If $x$ were $1/4$ or greater, we'd have
$$n\ge n+\frac1{16}$$